# Fetching common elements using XQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am stuck with a problem using XQuery to return common elements based on a tag. I am trying to write a XQ function which returns the common elements. For example I have an XML as:
$schoolA

```
<schoolA>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <students>1000</students>
    <classes>25</classes>
</schoolA>
<schoolA>
    <name>DEF</name>
    <students>1200</students>
    <classes>20</classes>
</schoolA>
<schoolA>
    <name>GHY</name>
    <students>900</students>
    <classes>30</classes>
</schoolA>
```

The other one as:
$schoolB

```
<schoolB>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <students>1000</students>
    <classes>25</classes>
</schoolB>
<schoolB>
    <name>DEF</name>
    <students>1200</students>
    <classes>20</classes>
</schoolB>
<schoolB>
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <students>1100</students>
    <classes>30</classes>
</schoolB>
```

The function should return:
$commonSchool

```
<schoolA>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <students>1000</students>
    <classes>25</classes>
</schoolA>
<schoolA>
    <name>DEF</name>
    <students>1200</students>
    <classes>20</classes>
</schoolA>
```

The matching factor is the name. I am trying to write a nested for loop, but stuck appending the element to a variable. Any clues on how to do it would be great!

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: XQuery 1.0 or 3.0/3.1? In 3.0/3.1 you can use the new "group by" construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XQuery function matches two sequences of elements based on the value of the `<name>` element. Assumption for simplicity is that you have wrapped your two sets of School elements in a wrapper called `<schools>`.

This works with XQuery 1.0.

```
declare namespace _="http://local/funcs";

declare function _:munge($schoolA as element()*, $schoolB as element()*) {
    $schoolA[name=$schoolB/name]
};

_:munge(schools/schoolA, schools/schoolB)
```

Comment: Or more simply, the body of the function can be `$schoolA[name=$schoolB/name]`

Comment: Unfortunately the application uses v1.0. I will give the suggestions a try! Thanks!

Comment: Turned this into a self-contained example, incorporated Michael's improvement, and verified XQuery 1.0 compatibility